# Are the following statements relating to sequential characterization of limits true or false?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing

Here is the information, and the statements:

> Let {$x_n$} be a sequence whose limit is $a \in \mathbb R$, and such that $x_n \not=a$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$. And let $F$ be a function which is defined on an open interval containing a.
>
> 1) If there exists {$x_n$} (which tends to $a$ and $xn≠a$), $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}F(x_{2n})=L$ then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}F(x)=L$
>
> 2) If for all {$x_n$} (which tends to $a$ and $xn≠a$), $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}F(x_{2n})=L$ then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}F(x)=L$

I want to know which of the statements (if not both) are true. This is what I've done so far, with my reasoning for why.

> Statement 1 is true.
>
> If $\exists \space \{x_n\}$ s.t $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}F(x_{2n})=L$ then $L=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}F(x_{2n})=F(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_{2n})=F(a)=L$
>
> Since F is defined on an open interval containing $a$, that implies that F is continuous. Given this, for any sequence {$b_n$} that is also bounded by $a$, $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n=a$. Thus we can conclude that for  if there exists a sequence {$x_n$} s.t $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}F(x_{2n})=L$, then for any sequence {$x_n$} $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}F(x_{2n})=L$. Now since F is continuous around $a$, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}F(x)=F(a)=L$, thus the statement is true

-

> Statement 2 is true.
>
> If $\forall \space \{x_n\}$, $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}F(x_{2n})=L$ then $L=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}F(x_{2n})=F(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_{2n})=F(a)=L$
>
> Now since F is defined on an open interval containing $a$, this implies that F is continuous around $a$, meaning that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a}F(x)$ = F(a) =L

Comment: I don't think the statement " since $F$ is defined on an open interval containing $a$, this implies that $F$ is continuous around $a$" is true. For example the indicator function of $\mathbb{Q}$ is defined in the neighbourhood of $0$ and is not continuous around $0$.

Comment: "Function" is a very broad term. If $F(x)=0$ for real $x\ne 0$ and $F(a)=1$ then $F$ is a function.

Answer (score 0):

In the proof of the first statement you use:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} F(y_n) = F\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n\right)$$

There's a theorem that states this **for continuous $F$**, but the statement is not true in general.